# How could I remove "error C4335: Mac file format detected" in VC 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am now compiling a project with VC++ 2008, and the error I have obtained is as follows:

```
Error   7   error C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format
```

I was wondering how I could solve this kind of errors. I have found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aad7fash.aspx) useful but the solution is suitable for VC++ 2010 rather than VC++ 2008. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For VS2012 select and open the file within solution explorer. File->Advanced Save Options-> Set Encoding: Western European (Windows) && Set Line endings: Unix

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this addon](http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php) to make the conversions automatically across your project, it's extremely easy.

Answer (score 1):

Just save it in the format you want; VC+ 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aad7fash(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can open your file with Sublime Text, then open "View"->"Line Endings"->Unix/Windows. Then save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Mac formatted files contain `\r` at the end of each line and that can cause in some cases compilation errors. Just remove the `\r` in each end of line and only use `'\n'` and try again. This warning should be then gone.
See also https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mac-os-x/0596004605/ch01s06.html